# How do I enable prod?

Tags: symfony

When I visit my Symfony2 project using app_dev.php, I see my site. When I visit it using app.php, I see the Symfony2 Welcome page that comes up for new projects.

I haven't put anything in my config_dev.yml or routing_dev.yml files. I've run `php app/console cache:clear`. Why can't I see my project outside of development mode?

Here is my routing.yml

```
_welcome:
    resource: "@FooBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

and my routing_dev.yml

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SymfonyWebConfiguratorBundle/Resources/config/routing/configurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

and FooBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: FooBundle:Default:index }

(other stuff...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running this:

```
php app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

Also you could try debugging routes with:

```
php app/console --env=prod router:debug
```

Comment: Indeed, you must explicitly specify the prod environment, or cache:clear will only act on dev. This is probably something of a safety net feature to help prevent you from continually wiping your production cache during extensive testing.

Comment: Didn't realize that the routing was cached too. Thanks!

Comment: @flu I don't think that the second command does refer to the caching of routes - `router:debug` tells you about all the routes in your app.  See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the clarification. In my case I was referring to the clearing of the cache, not the debugging of the routes but it may help someone else not to confuse the outcomes of these two very different commands.

Comment: @flu Ah, I see.  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

To which `controller` did `routing.yml` and `routing_dev.yml` route with the following pattern?
`pattern:  /`

they should route to the same controller.

Please post your routing*.yml

Comment: Posted. What puzzles me is that routing_dev.yml uses resource routing.yml which uses @FooBundle's routing.yml as a resource. But routing.yml doesn't seem to work in production?